# Operator overloading return type problem in c++

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

Suppose this is the code

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const classname& rhs)
{
    //do sth
    return os;
}
```

It works good with cout<< classobj<<"etc";

However, the things I don't understand:

Why can't I return when I make return type ostream instead of "ostream&"; even return type being string does not work when I return string. It gives error without compiling

> C++ cannot overload functions that only have different return types

However, they differ with parameters  as well, so why is that a thing?

This is the declarations of them

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Schedule& rhs); // Schedule is class 
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Days& rhs); // Days is enum
```

2nd, if the return type to be the same "ostream&" and i return os which is "not" referenced, shouldn't it accept and return it as referenced os? it gives error as well.

Comment: Please show code that **does not work**, together with **full unedited** compiler errors. Do not show working code and then say "but if I tweak this and that it stops working". It is not useful.

Comment: Streams can't be copied. Returning by value returns a copy.

Comment: Your other error is presumably because you have two identical overloads of the stream operator that only differ by their return type, as with any function that's not allowed

Comment: The second issue cannot be reproduces with the code snippet presented in the question alone. My assumption is that you've got a incompatible declaration of the operator somewhere. (something like `ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const classname& rhs);`

Comment: No overloading on return type is not only for operators, it is the same for ordinary functions. With `int f(int);` and `float f(int);` the compiler cannot tell which function `f(5);` is supposed to call.

Comment: They do not differ in return type, its with parameters. Thats why I didn't get the first error. Also, no false declaration has been made. I guess 2nd one is caused by like someone said "the streams can't be copied". But I don't get the first one

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full compiler output

Comment: The overloading and operator parts are distractions, I believe. The fundamental "why not" reason is that you can't return something by value that can't be copied.

Comment: As for the _"C++ cannot overload functions that only have different return types"_ error: Most compilers will show the line of the offending declaration and the declarations you've shown are _not_ the declarations it is complaining about.

Comment: @steatoda If my answer doesn't explain the errors you get, will you please update the question with a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I return when I make return type ostream instead of "ostream&";

Because `std::ostream`s are not copyable.

> even return type being string does not work when I return string. It gives error without compiling
>
> > C++ cannot overload functions that only have different return types

There is already an overload for `operator<<` taking the same types of arguments. You can't add an overload where the only difference is the return type.

> if the return type to be the same "ostream&" and i return os which is "not" referenced, shouldn't it accept and return it as referenced os? it gives error as well.

I assume you mean that you are trying to take the `ostream` argument by value:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream os, const classname& rhs) {
    //                              ^ not a reference 
    return os;
}
```

This would return a dangling reference since `os` is local to the function. And again, `ostream`s are not copyable so you can't take it by value anyway.

Comment: The thing is, they are not taking the same arguments, one of them takes class obj, other one takes enum obj, thats why I'm confused

Comment: @steatoda Please add the overloads you've got to the question and I'll see if I can explain it.

Comment: I added the declarations

Comment: @steatoda I [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/EaWdGKccM) your error using the given declarations. You need to add a [mre] to the question.

Comment: @steatoda you add normal declarations, none of the attempted declarations that you say you are in trouble with.